# Javascript doesn't seem to be processing JSON api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, openweathermap

I'm trying to make a page that will use the openweathermap api to display the user's city and local temperature, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be processing the JSON api and is doing nothing. My code is fine as far as I can tell so I don't understand what's wrong. 
Here's the jsfiddle link and javscript code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/qo2h1L9e/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var data;
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lon = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(lat);
      console.log(lon);
      console.log("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=4907e373098f091c293b36b92d8f0886");
      $.getJSON("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=4907e373098f091c293b36b92d8f0886", function(json) {
        data = json;
        console.log(data.name);
        $("#city").text(data.name);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Addresses are assumed relative to the current `window.location` and `api.openweathermap.org` can also be a valid directory name. Include the protocol and `//` anchor within the address to have it recognized as a hostname – `"http://api.openweathermap.org/..."`

Comment: I did as you recommended and it didn't help. When I take the url from the console and put it into the address bar in my search engine I get the  desired JSON object on my page but my code doesn't seem to be receiving it for some reason.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Browsers will typically log reasons for Ajax requests failing in their Consoles.

Comment: It was giving me an error 404 before but somehow (I didn't change anything) it just started working. I'm even more confused than before about this but I'm not gonna complain.

Comment: Maybe your advice had a delayed effect? :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when coding this. Assuming you're on FCC?

Anyways, try adding &callback=? to the api URL. You may need to get the data as JSONP rather than JSON.

Also, you don't need to define data. You could access the object directly through the json parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it jQuery try this code

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var data;
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
                    console.log(lat);
                    console.log(lon);
                    console.log("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=4907e373098f091c293b36b92d8f0886");
//                    $.getJSON("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=4907e373098f091c293b36b92d8f0886", function(json) {
//                        data = json;
//                        console.log(data.name);
//                        $("#city").text(data.name);
                    //                    });
                    var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
                    var params = {};
                    params.lat = lat;
                    params.lon = lon;
                    params.APPID = "4907e373098f091c293b36b92d8f0886";

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: url,
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: params,
                        success: function (res) {
                            console.log(res);
                        },
                        error: function (res) {
                        }
                    });


                }
                );
            }
        });
```

The problem is in `json`.For cross domain use `jsonp`.